# Can't add new sections to the existing pages on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I've received a wordpress site for some changes. They've asked me to add social feed on it. When I tried, I can edit the existing content but I can't add any new section into it. And I installed some editors to edit the pages but none of them are working. The editors are working fine on the newly created pages by myself. I don't know what cause this.

Comment: @gvgvgvijayan will you help me to resolve this?

Comment: Hi You might need to add more information on what are you trying to do, social feed normally is added by widgets or plugins or custom code, unless your using  visual builder, you might need to check its options

Comment: This question is way too broad for us to help. What theme are you using? Are you editing the template files? Are you trying to do this in a Theme Editor/Customize section? Not all WP sites are the same.

Comment: I tried changing the theme to default Twenty Twenty-one and everything is working fine. I can edit the pages with editor (elementor). But when I switched to the theme that my client uses, the trouble starts. I've asked them for the theme details. They said that it was an personally developed theme from another person.@disinfor